# Atomic write of 2k+ documents in Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a use case where I want to create: 1 document, which has a collection "locations" which needs to have more than 2000 documents.

Every document has 4-5 fields, nothing huge, but every document is its own network request, and it takes ages to create them on Firestore.

Is there any better way to do this? Batched writes have up to 500 object creations limit and support set, update and delete (not create).

Comment: won't `set` create a document if it doesn't already exist?

Comment: Please don't post the solution in your question, as it's very confusing for people who find your question in the future. Either post it as a separate answer, or suggest it as an edit to Alex' answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most appropriate solution for this problem is to use [batch operations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes). So you can execute multiple write operations as a single batch even if you are only using the `set()` method, which actually adds a document at specific reference. The single issue in here is that you cannot add more than 500, so you should create a mechanism to add all 2000 documents in 500 chunks. So 4 batch operations will be needed.

Comment: In that case, you should pass a document reference that contains an autogenerated ID. So having a collection reference, you can simply generate the id and then pass that id to the document() function.

Comment: Thx @Alex, I have succeeded. Question updated with solution code.